# Can't access new uploaded laravel site to server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

i've uploaded my laravel4 site to a live server for the first time.

When trying to visit the site on the server i get this error: http://www.eversite.be/laravel/public/

And i also noticed that the /public/ folder isn't visible in the document tree: http://www.eversite.be/laravel/

I looked up the problem on stackoverflow and found this solution but that didn't help:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel/public

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I still have the same error:

Please help

Comment: Look....if you enter this url on your browser http://www.eversite.be/laravel/ ....well, there is no public folder....did you check the perms on the public folder?...or, if you delete the url rewrite condition...the public folder is visible??...if not, then is all about perms

Comment: Check Apache logs. There you can find the reason.

Comment: Make sure that app/storage is writable by Apache. Also, you should move the entire Laravel package outside of the web server root.  Move it to /var/www (or whatever makes sense for your server), put the public folder in /var/www/html/some-folder-name, and then bootstrap Laravel from there.

Comment: Robert, if i delete the .htaccess file in /public then the folder is visible under eversite.be/laravel, what now? I have also set the write permissions on app/storage and /public

Comment: Your web server returns *HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error* when a client is trying to fetch Laravel's `index.php` page - my guess is that the references to `autoload.php` and `start.php` are pointing to wrong locations. You will definitely find more information from the Apache error logs.

In a related note, you should not have your whole Laravel tree accessible via HTTP service. It would be better to have only the *public* folder in your web tree. To do this, you need to update the above-mentioned file references within `index.php`.